# how to create a tablespace in oracle with initial data size of 10MB and let it grow all the way to the capacity of the disk?

Tags: oracle

how to create a tablespace in oracle with initial data size of 10MB and let it grow all the way to the capacity of the disk? so if the disk is 100GB the table should be able to grow until 100GB without any change in the configuration

Answer (score 0):

Use `MAXSIZE` ( IMHO I don't think it's a good idea to fill your disk )

```
CREATE BIGFILE TABLESPACE BIGTBS1 DATAFILE '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/OCM/bigtbs01.dbf'
SIZE 10M AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 10M MAXSIZE 100G;
```